# Sugarcrm disable confirm popup before leaving

Tags: php, jquery, sugarcrm

When there is some changes in the form and if user try to navigate to other page, sugarcrm asks confirmation in a popup to leave.

How to disable this functionality in sugarcrm 7?

**Update**

Actually i am exporting a csv. The file get downloaded on the first click of the button.

When i click the button for second time it is showing confirmation popup as in in the attachment. [image]

Comment: Is it a community edition?

Comment: No. It is a professional edition

Comment: check the solution in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment out everything in `CloseActivityPanel` function and after commenting your code will be this only as follows:

```
    closeActivityPanel: {
    show:function(module,id,new_status,viewType,parentContainerId){
        if (SUGAR.util.closeActivityPanel.panel)
   SUGAR.util.closeActivityPanel.panel.destroy();
     var singleModule = SUGAR.language.get("app_list_strings", "moduleListSingular")[module];
     singleModule = typeof(singleModule != 'undefined') ? singleModule.toLowerCase() : '';
     var closeText =  SUGAR.language.get("app_strings", "LBL_CLOSE_ACTIVITY_CONFIRM").replace("#module#",singleModule);
                        var args = "action=save&id=" + id + "&record=" + id + "&status=" + new_status + "&module=" + module;
                        var callback = {
                            success:function(o)
                            {
                               window.setTimeout(function(){if(document.getElementById('search_form')) document.getElementById('search_form').submit(); else window.location.reload(true);}, 0);
                            },
                            argument:{'parentContainerId':parentContainerId}
                        };

                        YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'index.php', callback, args);
    }
},
```

This way confirmation pop will not come.

In case if you wants to disable `onbeforeunload` then use the following code according to your requirement.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event){
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

Comment: I think this code is to disable the popup displayed by sugarcrm. But i need to disable the alert box displayed by the browser which may be calling from the event "onbeforeunload". Sorry i should have brief it.

Comment: ohh so just apply on suitable place the code ` window.onbeforeunload = null;` e.g. 
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event){
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
});

Comment: Issue fixed by placing `window.onbeforeunload = null;' code on onClick attribute of that button. Thanks @Deep Kakkar.

Comment: `'buttons' => array (0 => array ('customCode' => '<input type="submit" value="{sugar_translate label=\'LBL_EXPORT_CSV\' name="button" onclick="window.onbeforeunload = null; return  exportCSV();" class="button" accesskey="A" title="Export CSV [Alt+A]" id="btn_export_csv" />' ),)`  Used this code in vardef file. Posting for user reference. :)

Comment: great, it helps  :)